# How is the zero flag set in terms of hardware?

Tags: digital-logic, computer-architecture, alu

I'm angling this as a general question on the *assumption* that it doesn't differ significantly with architecture - at least at the level I'm asking.

I'm curious how - in terms of hardware, not the obvious 'result is zero' - the zero flag/status bit is set (or cleared for that matter).

It never really occurred to me before, but it seems a fairly intensive task, at least relative to say, a carry or overflow flag. Am I correct in thinking there's no way to know the result is zero, other than to check each bit?

Unless I'm missing something obvious, it seems that it must take 'a lot' (if that's sensible to say in \$\text{ns}\$) longer than determining the overflow, and the carry status of course is 'already there' as a consequence of the operation.

My question, really, is just how is it 'usually' implemented?

Comment: N-input OR gate followed by a NOT gate? Checking each bit isn't very intensive when you can check all the bits in parallel.

Comment: I see that, but that's not '*that*' parallel - all the bits have to be OR'd together ultimately, so the number of ops increases with N!. I realise it's still fast in an absolute sense, but it's a lot slower than determining C/V flags isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, [this question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4194/how-to-find-out-if-a-binary-number-is-zero?rq=1) is not only related, but wholly the same. I couldn't find it before I posted, and wasn't suggested from my title, but I just saw it in the sidebar. Sorry!

Comment: An N-input gate is still a single gate delay up to something like 8 inputs. If you needed two stages, that would be sufficient for 64 bits parallel, so it's increasing with log2(N)/K, where K is log2 of the maximum number of inputs for one gate delay, not N and certainly not N!.

Comment: @Spehro Pehfhany - I wasn't aware of that until the question I linked/your comment. It makes sense now, I just had a 'I must be missing something' feeling..

Comment: Also I meant sum of the n terms to n, not n!. So n^2 I suppose. But anyway, I was wrong. :)

Comment: @dave-tweed - thanks for marking as dupe. I'm a relative SE noob, but I've never seen these options, does it require certain rep? And OP can't do if (like I did) later discovers a duplicate?

Comment: It's one of the options that you get when you click the "close" button under the question. Normally, the decision to close is arrived at via voting by the community, but since you identified the dupe yourself, I went ahead and "short circuited" the process and did it directly. I'm a moderator (that's what the diamond means), so my votes take effect imeediately. I'm very careful about when I take such actions, but in this case, it seemed entirely appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

An n input NOR gate will do the hardware implementation.

Comment: No, it won't... A NOR would, but a NAND would only check against -1.

Comment: My mistake. Corrected.