# Checking Bitstring for == 0, then set a zero bit = 1 in ALU

Tags: alu

I am trying to model an ALU to implement a shift operation.
When the shift operation is done, I should check if the result is 0. If a result == 0 is found, I want to set a single result bit to 1.

I was thinking about NOR-ing all the bits, but since I'm implementing this for a 32-bit ALU, that doesn't seem to be the right way.

Is there an easy way to find out if a 32-bit string == 0 and set a single bit if that's the case?

Here's a pic of my ALU:

[image: alu]

I want to insert some kind of logic where the "?" is.

Comment: Why do you think it's not the right way?

Comment: It seems like it would be too much logic for just getting 1 Bit. I guess I shouldve said "not the best way" ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find out if a binary number is zero](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4194/how-to-find-out-if-a-binary-number-is-zero)

Comment: But that's what K-map reduces the expression to. Do you think you can reduce it further?

Comment: Yes, Thank you!